# Airflow webserver on kubernetes showing UTC timezone when enviroment variable is different

Tags: airflow

I deployed my airflow on kubernetes using helm, with this chart: **stable/airflow**

I also am using this image:

```
  image:
    repository: apache/airflow
    tag: latest
    ## values: Always or IfNotPresent
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecret: ""
```

And I added this two variables to the enviroment variables, to change the timezone:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: America/New_York
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: America/New_York
```

But when I go to airflow it shows me the UTC timezone:

[image]

But in the configuration part of airflow I see that airflow captured the timezone on the ui:

```
webserver   default_ui_timezone     America/New_York    env var
```

TL/DR: airflow on kubernetes getting timezoen configuration from enviroment variable but showing on wrong timezone.

Any ideas everyone?

Comment: Have you try to change default_timezone parameter on airflow.cfg? This parameter has default value for UTC timezone that`s why your dag is getting UTC tz. Also on the new release of airflow(Airflow 1.10.10) this type o change can be done by WebServer User Interface